# In pycharm professional version,pyspark package installation error

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

When the pycharm professional version installs the pyspark package, an error occurs when installing the package 'pyspark'. The description shows 'No package description around on PyPI'. It can still be installed with conda.

I want to be able to install the pysark package.